# Running Report Studio on LocalHost

Tags: sql, reporting-services

Am having problems, does any one have any suggestions, but have reporting working in reporting studio where I can build and preview a report however I cannot run the program in localhost?
I have correctly installed reporting services etc though.

Comment: Can you provide more details as to what you mean by " I cannot run the program in localhost". Presumably you are deploying the report from Visual Studio, does it deploy correctly or are there errors? Are you able to browse the Report Manager site? It would also help if you mentioned what version of Reporting Services you are using.

Comment: When I build and preview any of my reports they show correctly without any errors.The copy I am currently running is the latest copy downloaded from the internet - 2 days fresh. I am not sure what you are refering to when you say the report manager site?

Comment: You should probably take a look at a Reporting Services architecture overview, e.g. this one http://nirajrules.wordpress.com/2009/12/29/sql-server-reporting-services-ssrs-architecture-overview/

Comment: When you design and preview the reports, you are most likely doing this in the Report Designer (actually Visual Studio). Reports are then normally deployed (uploaded) to the actual Report Server (this is the underlying database and web service of the Reporting Services product). Report Manager is a web application supplied by MS that provides a user interface to the web service. I'm guessing that when you refer to "localhost" you're trying to look at the reports in Report Manager on the server on which it is installed. This would normally be on the URL http://localhost/reports. Is that right?